# How do I sort bar chart by value with R ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my simple assets dataset:

```
ID  Type    Currency    Value
a   Bond    GBP         10
b   Bond    EUR         20
c   Stock   GBP         3
d   Stock   GBP         60
e   Bond    GBP         8
f   Bond    USD         39
g   Stock   USD         1
```

Here is the code:

```
 assets <- read_excel("C:/R/SampleData.xlsx")
 g <- ggplot(assets, aes(Currency, Value))
 g + geom_col()
```

And this is the plot that I get:

[image: bar plot]

I am trying to create the same plot, but with bars sorted  by value (in descending order)
How do I achieve this?
I have tried the following code:

```
assets$Currency <- factor(assets$Currency, levels = assets$Currency[order(assets$Value)])
```

But I get the following warning message and the chart is still not sorted correctly:

```
Warning message:
In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `assets$Currency <- reorder(assets$Currency, assets$Value, sum)`

Answer (score 20):

```
  ggplot(assets, aes(reorder(Currency, -Value, sum), Value)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: By default `reorder` works based on the `mean` of the observations. If you want to sort by total bar height, you need to explicitly set the function to `sum`

Comment: You're right. I edited to reflect that